# Order by counter cache in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, caching

I have two objects:

Tplan

```
class Tplan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tplangroup, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Tplangroup

```
class Tplangroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tplans
end
```

My counter cache works and increments fine on a column called tplans_count within the tplangroups table. If I want to `:order => 'tplans_count desc'`, where would I put this in the model?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could create a **default scope** in your model like so:

```
class Tplangroup < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tplans
    default_scope order('tplans_count DESC')
end
```

Comment: [Avoid default_scope](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/806-default_scope-is-evil).

Comment: @Zabba: I do not agree. Of course if you do something in your code you expect it to work as it is supposed to. If you can't remember that you created a `default_scope`, then yes, don't use it.

Comment: Right, but how does creating a `default_scope` make sense here? And if the order is desired to be `ASC`, you would have: `Tplangroup.unscoped.order('tplans_count ASC')`.
And you would potentially use `unscoped` for every other scope you might need. [And one more reason here](http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2012/03/be-careful-using-default_scope-and-order.html).

Comment: @Sparda  If I wanted to create a specific scope for this instance, how would I refer to it in the controller?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand here... scopes are class level, not instance level.
@Zabba I did not say it was a flawless approach, it works just great if you're absolutely sure you'll always want the scope to apply no matter what ; )